# What are other ways to override css other than !Important and specificity of the item?

Tags: html, css

Okay, here's the thing: I'm editing a stylesheet and can't edit the HTML - only CSS, and I have to override some other things and !important and specificity aren't doing it. How do I override CSS further?

Comment: I'm afraid if you have no control over the HTML or JavaScript, `!important` and CSS specifity are your only options. Please show us some code to tell us where's the problem. It's very likely you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you only have the one stylesheet to play with? could you @import a custom one?

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to override inline styles? If that's the case I'm afraid you can't do it as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

css takes the last loaded value for a certain styleblock. if you make sure you insert your own css file as last and there are no !important signs before it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override inline styles than the only way is to have ID-Selectors with !important.

I do not know your scenario, but when you want to override `inline !important styles` then your only way (as far as I know) is to have a `user style sheet` in your browser which can beat the inline CSS when it is !important, too.

With `author style sheets` you cannot beat `inline !important styles` - as far as I know.

A nice link for that: [CSS Cascade](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-cascade/)